# What’s technology used in the Badge system in stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, technology

Is it CEP-related? I want to enable similar badges in my own web applications, do you have any suggestions?

P.S. Here `CEP` means `Complex Event Processing`.

Comment: What is CEP? I don't know this term.

Comment: Is this the CEP you are referring to? [Complex event processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_event_processing)

Comment: I think he means the [Certificate Enrolment Protocol](http://www.cryer.co.uk/glossary/c/index.htm).

Comment: Here CEP stands for `Complex event processing`